# How to run NodeJs SocketIO on server (Centos 7)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, centos, centos7

I create app with nodejs socket io. It works clearly at localhost (port: 3000). But when i deploy it to my server in there i can run my app on 3000 port but client side throw timeout. How can i solve it?

```
var fs = require('fs');

var https = require('https');
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('ssl.my-key.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl.my-cert.crt')
};
var server = https.createServer(options);
var io  = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var port = 3000;

const database = require('./Database');

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

  socket.on('message', async (msg) => {
    // I do some action here.
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', (msg) => {
    // some action in here too
  });

});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

Comment: It might possible that port 3000 isn't available on your server or might be in use. so better to use process.env.PORT || 3000 while deploying over server

Comment: Maybe you need to do port forwarding? you haven't port forwarded your server to your network or through your router?

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya yes. i do so. but nothing.

Comment: @MuhandJumah how can i forward port?

Comment: @MirnamiqAbdullayev check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your issue is with port forwarding.
In order for your server to be publicly accessed, it needs to have all ports forwarded appropriately. Locally and on the router.

Check this link to learn more about how to port forward on linux: https://linuxacademy.com/guide/11630-internal-port-forwarding-on-linux-using-the-firewall/

And this to learn more about router port forwarding, but this will really depend on your  router.

https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/general-port-forwarding-guide/

However, I don't recommend you to take care of hosting on your own machine(s). I 
suggest you use Heroku, you can op in for their free servers, you don't need to pay.

More about heroku and NodeJS: https://linuxacademy.com/guide/11630-internal-port-forwarding-on-linux-using-the-firewall/

Comment: if i change port 443 to another all application will be change? Because there are a lot of application in this server. Yesterday i want to forward port such as your first link but all application stoped. i remove changes then they work again .

Comment: You need to make sure no other application/server is running on that port, you can run something like this command `netstat -tulpn | grep :443` or anyport you want

Comment: yes. running app `[root@panel public_html]# netstat -tulpn | grep :443
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26638/nginx: master `

Comment: Why do you want to change to port 443? try picking a different port that's not being used, something like 3000

Comment: how can i do? @MuhandJumah

Comment: What port is your server running on? if your server is running on port 3000(which from your code it looks like it) then follow the link I sent you but forward port 3000 not 443

Comment: `netstat -tulpn | grep :3000` i run this command. `[root@panel ~]# netstat -tulpn | grep :3000
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      11438/node `

Comment: That’s good. You don’t need to do anything right now except port forward 3000 and make sure to run your app from terminal on centos

Comment: Follow the links in my answer as to how to port forward, but don’t portforward 443. Port forward 3000

Answer (score 1):

let we debug your node js app.
1) add some logs on database connection, http.createserver, also where you have to check if not success then catch exception

2) you should have to open port on centOs before start your node js app

3) you should have test you with domain name or ip address

as per you comment you got connection timeout , you mean node js server trying to connect with port 3000 but node not able to connect and its throws error with connection timeout

also send your sample code of your main index file so we can investigate your problen
thanks.

Comment: [root@panel public_html]# node index.js
listening on *:3000